# ParseException while retrieving comments from Youtube video

Tags: xml-parsing, youtube-api, gdata

I want to get all comments (up to 999) from a youtube video. This is the URL that i want to send

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1EEFydL6ooA/comments?start-index=1&max-results=50

When I send this URL i am getting **com.google.gdata.util.ParseException [Line 1, Column 279] Invalid root element, expected (namespace uri:local name) of (http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:entry), found (http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom:feed**

Actually, when my URL was "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1EEFydL6ooA", I was getting 25 comments if any. However since this is about one single video, I was not able to set max-results and start-index parameter. My code is :

```
    String str = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId
        + "/comments";
    YouTubeQuery youtubeQuery = new YouTubeQuery(new URL(str));
    youtubeQuery.setMaxResults(50);
    youtubeQuery.setStartIndex(1);
    String videoEntryUrl = youtubeQuery.getUrl().toString();
    VideoEntry videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryUrl),
            VideoEntry.class);
    if (videoEntry.getComments() != null) {
        String commentUrl = videoEntry.getComments().getFeedLink()
                .getHref();
        System.out.println(commentUrl);
        CommentFeed commentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(commentUrl),
                CommentFeed.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < commentFeed.getEntries().size()
                && commentFeed.getEntries().get(i) != null; i++) {

            String author=commentFeed.getEntries().get(i).getAuthors().get(0)
                            .getUri().substring(41)
            String commentId=commentFeed.getEntries().get(i).getId().substring(47);
            String comment=commentFeed.getEntries().get(i).getPlainTextContent();
```

Why am I getting parseException? Maybe because this code works accordingly VideoEntry object and parsing is done in this way. Is there something like CommentEntry? How can initiliaze it if any?

Note that my exception is not " com.google.gdata.util.ParseException: [Line 1, Column 101152, element yt:state] Invalid value for attribute : 'name' " which is due to wrong library.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't try your code. It looks like the PHP library.
It seems to me, that your using the wrong class. The url at the start is about comments, although you refer to it as a videoEntry.

(1)
This is about comments (since you append "/comments"):

```
String str = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId + "/comments";
```

(2)
    YouTubeQuery youtubeQuery = new YouTubeQuery(new URL(str));

```
youtubeQuery.setMaxResults(50);
youtubeQuery.setStartIndex(1);
```

(3)
Although you name it "videoEntry" it is about "comments", due to the value of the url:

```
String videoEntryUrl = youtubeQuery.getUrl().toString();

VideoEntry videoEntry = service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryUrl), VideoEntry.class);
```

Instead of the above, maybe try something like:

```
String myUrl = youtubeQuery.getUrl().toString();  // only another name

CommentFeed commentFeed = service.getFeed(new URL(myUrl), CommentFeed.class); // Feed response
```

BTW: In the PHP library it detects the class of the feed by itself and the second parameter can be left null. Like: CommentFeed commentFeed = service.getEntry(new URL(myUrl));

Comment: BTW. The PHP library uses: $youTubeService>setMajorProtocolVersion(2); To use api version 2. (The "v=2" parameter in the URL.)

Comment: It is about to comments because i want it to be about "comments" It was not about "comments" before i have not appended "/comments" in that URL. I just want to create an CommentEntry object by using this URL but i am not able to do this

Comment: In your code, in line 7: "service.getEntry(new URL(videoEntryUrl),
            VideoEntry.class);". Here videoEntryUrl is "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoId + "/comments"; This is a feed of comments. Therefor using VideoEntry.class is wrong.

Comment: I know my using VideoEntry.class is wrong. I want something else. My code works when URL was "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+ videoID. However, since it is just for 1 video, i cannot use max-results and start-index parameters. Therefore, i need to use feed of Comments. So, instead of changing my URL, i have to change my VideoEntry. I need CommentEntry, dont I? But I cant use CommentENtry class

Comment: I don't think so. Depending on the url you send, the response will be an entry or a feed. Using the url "gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"+ videoID the response is an entry. This video-entry contains an url for its comments-feed, which you can either get from that video-entry or compose it yourself; which you are doing here at the start of your code. Here you start right away with the comments feed. Reading the response (a comment feed), each step will be a commentEntry.

Comment: Or, after getting the video entry first. From that entry the url for the comments-feed. Here you set the start-index an max-results. So not at the start.

Comment: So, I was not getting what you are saying. It is done now thanks :)